# Python functools.namedtuple

Tags: python, python-idle

I am aware of the existence and purpose of `collections.namedtuple`, but I have noticed that, at least in IDLE (3.2.2), this factory function is also in `functools`:

```
>>> import functools
>>> functools.namedtuple
<function namedtuple at 0x024B41E0>
```

It also exists in `collections` as expected, and is the same function:

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.namedtuple is functools.namedtuple
True
```

No docs I can find ever mention `namedtuple` being anywhere other than collections. So: is this standard, or just an IDLE weirdness? If it's just IDLE, is it a bug or a Why would `namedtuple` be in two places - and, indeed, in whose warped mind does it make sense in `functools` of all places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3.2.2, `functools.py` contains the following import:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple
```

It seems pretty clear that it's just a convenience import for the module's implementation, and is not intended to be part of its public interface.